# Loading Excel files in Java takes too much time

Tags: java, excel

I would like to load an Excel file into a Java program, parse it  and insert the necessary things into a database every day, but don't want to load the whole file every time when I run the program. I need to get last 90 rows only. Is it possible to load an Excel (XLSM) file partially in Java (not necessary but preferred, can be another programing language too) to decrease loading time?

It takes around 60-70 seconds, and loading Excel takes 35 seconds, Excel file has 4000 rows and rows has 900 columns.

```java
try{
    workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    rowSize=sheet.getLastRowNum();
    myWriter = new FileWriter("/Users/mykyusuf/Desktop/filename.txt");
    Row malzeme=sheet.getRow(1);
    Row kaynak=sheet.getRow(2);
    Row endeks=sheet.getRow(3);

    myWriter.write("insert all\n");
    Row row=sheet.getRow(rowSize-1);
    for (int i = 4; i < rowSize-1; i++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(i);
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (cell.getColumnIndex()>3) {
                myWriter.write("into piyasa_takip (tarih,malzeme,kaynak,endeks,deger) values (to_date(\'" + row.getCell(3).getLocalDateTimeCellValue().toLocalDate() + "\','YYYY-MM-DD'),\'" + malzeme.getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()) + "\',\'" + kaynak.getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()) + "\',\'" + endeks.getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()) + "\',\'" + cell + "\')\n");
            }
        }
    }

    row = sheet.getRow(rowSize-1);

    for (Cell cell : row) {
        if (cell.getColumnIndex()>3 ) {
            myWriter.write("into piyasa_takip (tarih,malzeme,kaynak,endeks,deger) values (to_date(\'" + row.getCell(3).getLocalDateTimeCellValue().toLocalDate() + "\','YYYY-MM-DD'),\'" + malzeme.getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()) + "\',\'" + kaynak.getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()) + "\',\'" + endeks.getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()) + "\',\'" + cell + "\')\n");
        }
    }

    myWriter.write(" Select * from DUAL\n");

    myWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And why don't you load it just once, and save all the data for the duration of the programs run-time? Then you don't need to reload the file.

Comment: There is a steaming version of apache poi, **SXSSF**, instead of reading the entire DOM, document object. With this API you can read only your part, and do not have that memory overhead.

Comment: load an excel file! Load it into what?

Comment: Excel is updated at the end of the days. So I need to run the program once a day. I meant "Load an excel file" for loading excel file into the running Java program then I parse it and use for some jobs

Comment: Please [edit] your question with new information, don't hide it in a comment. -- How big is the file, and how long is "too long"? -- However, since all these Excel formats "XLS..." are binary files with internal structures of different lengths, such a file has to be read from the first byte to the last to reveal certain ranges. -- Can the data converted into CSV (comma separated values) or TSV (tabulator separated values)? Check the time to do such a conversion, and then consider using a tool like "tail" to obtain the last lines, to read only these into your program.

Comment: Oh sorry, I edit it now. I m new here

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a simple answer to your question, but I want to help you figure it out

1. Exist two substantially different formats: *.XLS (old) and *.XLSX (new). In common case, new format more compact (because use zipping as part of "container").

2. I don't know simple way for "cut" last 90 rows from excel file. Especially, excel have a complicated format with tabs, formulas and hyperlinks (and scripts :-) ) in document.

But, we can use "divide and rule" principle. If you have a big excel file locally and this file wery slow loading on remote host, you can process fiel locally (for extracnt only new reccords in other file) and load to remote host this "modifications" only.

Thus, you divide the task into two parts: super-simple processing of a large file locally (to highlight the changed part) and normal and smart processing on a remote host.

Maybe this will help you?

Comment: Actually Excel file is not a local file. It will be uploaded by someone else from remote, I get it and check the latest added rows, then I add new rows into a database

Comment: > It will be uploaded by someone else from remote - maybe, "someone else" may use simple file pre-processing for extract last changes? For example, this is may be a part of script, activationg when file saving.

Comment: I guess the company doesn't want to do it for me, they only send me the whole excel everyday and say "get the last 90 rows and use it"

Comment: if "they only send me the whole excel" - excuse me, but you want decrease loading time "to remote host over internet" or time of loading file into your program?

Comment: My program loads an excel file into program and runs sql commands inside of the same program. Main problem is execution time of the program, it is around 60-70 seconds and loading excel file takes 30 seconds, nearly half of exec time

Comment: > "loading excel file takes 30 seconds" - maybe, you can add the code of loading to your question? this will make it easier to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use Free Spire.Xls to solve this.

I choose some data (70 rows and 8 columns ). It costs me 1-2 seconds to read them.
Hope it can help you to save some time.

And codes are right below:

```
import com.spire.xls.Workbook;
import com.spire.xls.Worksheet;

public class GetCellRange {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     //Load the sample document
     Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
     workbook.loadFromFile("sample.xlsx");
     //Get the first worksheet
     Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
     //Choose the output content
     for (int row = 1; row <= 70 ; row++) {
        for (int col = 1; col <= 8 ; col++) {
            System.out.println(worksheet.getCellRange(row,col).getValue() + "\t");
        }
            System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
}
```